# What is the limsup of $\sum \limits _{n=1}^\infty \frac{1+\sin{n}}{4}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

$$\sum \limits _{n=1}^\infty \frac{1+\sin{n}}{4}$$

I computed the first $70$ terms of this series. They are each between $0$ and $1$, but they jump around quite a bit and I can't seem to determine any kind of pattern. Any idea what the limsup of this series is? Or how to find it?

Comment: This series does not converge, so its limsup is $+\infty$. Though it does look interesting and nontrivial to show.

Comment: Since $1<\pi$ and $\sin(x)>0$ on alternate intervals of length $\pi$ the term $\sin n$ is infinitely often positive, so that at those terms $(1+\sin n)/4>1/4$, showing divergence since all the terms are nonnegative.

Answer (score 1):

The series is clearly divergent. Are you looking for the $\limsup$ of the *sequence* $\{(1 + \sin n)/4\}$?

Comment: No I was just confused about what the limsup might be for a divergent series. I suppose it's obvious that the limsup is $\infty$, as David H said in the comments

Comment: This answer looks like a comment really.